# Why is Visual Studio Application Timelines not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, diagnostic-tools

I'm trying to analyse performance of a WPF application using the Visual Studio 2015 *Application Timeline* tool. However, when I attempt to start the profiler, I receive the following error message:

> Diagnostics session failed to start.
>
> Failed to start trace session (0x00000005).

I've tried:

- running as a privileged user.
- a smaller toy WPF project.
- checking event log for clues.
- googling :)

No idea where to go next. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Have you installed VS2015 update 3? Do you have other Visual Studio versions installed on you machine? Try running both applications as the same user and at the same elevation level.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing, I've got update 3. I'm using VS2015 but I also have VS2013 and I think 2010 installed. I'm not sure what you mean by that last sentence, can you clarify?

Comment: To run the application under test as well as Visual Studio under the same user account and with the same privileges. Repairing Visual Studio, just because you can, may also help (though I doubt it). If you have other things installed that use the Profiler API (App Insights, or a memory/CPU profiler, you may need to turn that off).

Comment: I had SciTools memory profiler installed-- removed that, repaired VS, running application under test and VS as same user and permissions. Still the same error.